# How to write an Internet Account Plugin for Mac OS?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

There a several plugins for Mail, Contacts & Calendars on Mac OS, but I need new type of account with mail, contacts and calendars services. I don't want to add this account separately as a mail account, a contacts account and a calendars account.
I googled and found no document about these plugins. I just know they are located at /System/Library/InternetAccounts/*.iaplugin
Anyone know how can I create a new iaplugin?
Thank you

Comment: I have the same idea, but Apple may not release this feature to personal developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, you can't. The InternetAccount plugin API is not public.

Comment: That was four years ago. Did anything change?

Comment: @rbanffy I'm not aware of any changes to the situation.