# How do clients access the Internet Account database?

Tags: macos

My copy of Mavericks has a System Preference pane named "Internet Accounts" (which I think was also in Mountain Lion).  It edits a list of accounts for various Internet services.  Apple's apps and services can access this information, but is there a way for third-party apps to view the database?

Seeing the only [Internet Accounts query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14370807/1010226) I found (so far), and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371137/1010226), I'm not holding out hope.